# Как правильно вывести элементы стека используя итератор?

Tags: java, стек, итераторы

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом. Правильный вывод находится в методе test7(), но мой стек немного не правильно работает.
Как правильно переписать код?

Код + тест программы прилагаю ниже. Буду всем благодарен за помощь!!

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class StackImpl implements Stack {
    Object array[] = new Object[0];

    int top = -1;

    @Override
    public void push(Object element) {
        Object[] arrPush = new Object[array.length+1];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrPush.length; i++) {
            if (i == arrPush.length-1) {
                arrPush[i] = element;
            } else {
                arrPush[i] = array[i];
            }
        }

        array = new Object[arrPush.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = arrPush[i];
        }

        top++;
    }

    @Override
    public Object pop() {
        Object element = array[size()-1];

        if (top == -1) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        Object[] arrRemove = new Object[array.length-1];

        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < array.length; i++, j++) {
            if (i == top) {
                continue;
            } else {
                arrRemove[i] = array[i];
            }
        }

        array = new Object[arrRemove.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = arrRemove[i];
        }

        top--;
        return element;
    }

    @Override
    public Object top() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        array = new Object[0];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return array.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new IteratorImpl();
    }

    class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {
        int current = top;
        int currentRem = top;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current != -1;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            if (current == -1) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            int cursor = current;
            current = cursor - 1;
            return array[cursor];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            top--;

            Object arrRem[] = new Object[size()-1];

            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < size(); i++) {
                if (i != currentRem) arrRem[j++] = array[i];
            }

            array = new Object[arrRem.length];

            System.arraycopy(arrRem, 0, array, 0, arrRem.length);

            currentRem--;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (i == array.length - 1) stringBuilder.append(array[i]);
            else stringBuilder.append(array[i]).append(", ");
        }

        return "[" + stringBuilder.toString() + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test7();
    }

    private static void test7() {

        Stack stack = new StackImpl();
        stack.push("A");
        stack.push("B");
        stack.push("C");

        Iterator it = stack.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(stack);

        it = stack.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(stack);

        it = stack.iterator();

        System.out.println(it.next());
        it.remove();
        System.out.println(stack);

        /* an output must be as the following:
        *************************************
        C
        B
        A
        [B, C]
        C
        [B]
        B
        []
        *************************************
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack - это класс. Код не должен запуститься

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar почему он не должен запускаться? В данном случае я хотел реализовать свой собственный стэк

Comment: А, вы свой интерфейс использовали. Хоть назовите его иначе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {
    int currentStart = 0;
    int currentEnd = array.length -1;
    int cursor;
    boolean isStart = true; //признак что следущее значение брать с начала массива

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        int center = array.length / 2;
        boolean isChet = array.length % 2 == 0;
        return currentStart != (isChet ? center : center + 1 ) || currentEnd != (isChet ? center -1 : center );
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        if (currentStart == -1 && currentEnd == -1) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        cursor = isStart ? currentStart++ : currentEnd--;
        isStart = !isStart;
        return array[cursor];
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        Object arrRem[] = new Object[size()-1];

        for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            if (i != cursor) {
                arrRem[i < cursor ? i : i-1] = array[i];
            }
        }
        array = arrRem;
        cursor = isStart ? currentStart-- : currentEnd--;
    }
}
```

и переделал ваш тест -так нагляднее

```
private static void test7() {

    StackImpl stack = new StackImpl();
    for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
        stack.push( i );
    }

    System.out.println("стек: " + stack);
    System.out.println("обход всего стека");
    Iterator iterator = stack.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iterator.next());
    }

    System.out.println("===============================");
    System.out.println("печать с удалением элементов стека");
    iterator = stack.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        System.out.println(stack);
    }
}
```

Comment: А можно его реализовать таким образом, что б на выходе было то что я ожидаю от стека?

Comment: Можно сделать что угодно - но это тогда уже не стэк. У вас странная последовательность. Вы хотите сначала удалить первый элемент - как это делается в очереди по принципу FIFO, а на второй итерации удаляете последний элемент как в стэке и у вас остается значение по середине

Comment: Данное задание поставлено не мною, хотя я с вами согласен, что это будет не стек! Не подскажите как правильно реализовать неправильную конструкцию на выходе?

Comment: не совсем понятно как должен работать этот итератор, брать через один? Один сначала второй с конца?

Comment: Нужно брать после последнего вызова метода next(). Так же выйдет реализовать?

Comment: Вопрос как раз в том какое значение должен next() возвращать, судя по вашему тесту он должен идти так: A, C, B. В какой последовательности должны выдаваться элементы, если их будет 10 - например вот такая простая коллекция 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  в какой последовательности должны выдаваться элементы?

Comment: Если есть коллекция 0,1,2...9, то вывод должен быть задом наперед

Comment: Т.е. последний зашёл - первый Вышел

Comment: Так я про то и говорю, что оно у вас сейчас так и работает, просто тест у вас не тот вывод ждет

Comment: Точно, до этого вы говорили правильно. Нужно брать через один, сначала с первого элемента, а потом с конца.

Comment: Т.е. 0,9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5 так?

Comment: Да, как это можно правильно реализовать? Что-то я не понимаю...

Comment: я добавил в ответ как это можно реализовать

Comment: Здравствуйте, а можно ли это реализовать не меняя метод test7()?

Comment: вы можете его не менять, на работу самого итератора это никак не повлияет

Comment: К сожаленью вывод почему-то у меня A, C, B. Но должен быть C, B, A. Соответствено метод удаление работает не правильно(. Как исправить программу, что б не сломать ничего?

Comment: Вы сами подтвердили что >Нужно брать через один, сначала с первого элемента, а потом с конца. Один и тот же итератор не может при печати делать обход по одному, а при удалении по другому. Тогда уточняйте условия. Можно накрутить и два итератора, но это какое-то извращение

Comment: А разве у меня не через один должен удалять?

Comment: Это вы у меня спрашиваете :) ?  вчера мы говорили про такую последовательность >0,9,1,8,2,7,3,6,4,5

Comment: а я дурной, нужно удалять последний элемент. Извините за потраченое время. Буду безумно рад если посоветуете как лучше это сделать

Comment: Если по последнему, ваш вариант работает правильно, но при удалении такой последовательности как в вашем тесте вы не получите

Comment: Всё равно огромное вам спасибо! Думаю кому-то это, но пригодится